# How can I record a custom iOS Crashlytics exception as fatal rather than non-fatal?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have a fatal iOS crash that I have to record using `recordCustomExceptionName:reason:frameArray:` for various reasons. The current triage process at my company prioritizes fatal Crashlytics issues over non-fatal, so I want to mark it correctly as the fatal issue that it is. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being tracked and further explained on Github [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5771). For now, the feature does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fatalerror("This is a fatal error")` for iOS in xcode and `throw new RuntimeException("Test Crash");` for android and it'll be reported as a fatal crash in Crashlytics.

Comment: It has to use that method call, because it’s providing a custom stack trace for various complicated reasons